# How to establish API connection to a Trial Enterprise Edition org?

Tags: rest-api, integration, security, ssl

I have an enterprise edition free org. This has API access as I have connected to it over Postman via a connected app that I created. The problem I'm facing is that I want to connect to this org over a Java application that is also still in development in my local machine.

I have generated the necessary stubs from Enterprise, Metadata, Tooling WSDLs. I'm trying to login to the org through the EnterpriseConnection object. But I keep getting a **"PKIX path building failed"** error.

Full error: **PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

So, I also tried to create a Self-signed cert, and imported it in my java project. Still the same error.

I also exported the Keystore from my enterprise org and used in my Java project. still the same error,

Has someone here connected using a Self-signed cert to an org? How would I go about establishing the connection?

Please let me know if and why this does not deserve to be a question instead of downvoting, would help me ask better!

Thanks!

Comment: Really is confusing why questions are downvoted without any explanation. It would really help me frame better if downvoters also tell me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM, figured this out.

I had to get all the certificates needed to for the chain.

To do this, go to the org, click on the URL > View Site Information > Connection is Secure > Certificate is Valid

once you see a pop-up, click on the 'Details' tab and you will find an option to 'Export'

I exported all of the certificates into my project.

Once done, you can import these .crt files to a new krystore of your project.

Once you import them, you can use this .jks in your client.